# Duplicate item from linked list in new list

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Im trying to copy in deep a list of node .
for example my list is as below:

```
Node n = new Node(1,new Node(12, new Node(34, new Node(3, Node.NIL))));
```

and my function as :

```
    public Node copy() {

       Node initial= this;
       Node duplicate=new Node(initial.getItem());

       while(Node.NIL!=initial.getNext()){

           initial=initial.getNext();
           Object a = initial.getItem();
           duplicate.next=new Node(a);
       }

       return duplicate;
    }
```

so when I do that, the output list is duplicate[1,3]. I dont understand where are 12 and 34.

Comment: You are not updating your duplicate list properly, it will only have the first and the last node of the original list.

Comment: I think you are missing: duplicate = duplicate.getNext(); before the end of your loop.

Comment: You need to step through the code in your debugger but the problem is that you are creating just one node which only has a next value, i.e. the length has to be two.

Comment: ok . what should l do ?. l tested many things , but I'm still stuck

Comment: Keep a `temp` node initially pointing to the first element of the list to be copied and then iteratively allocate the next node value from the original list to `temp.next ` and advance `temp=temp.next`.

Comment: With linked lists, I suggest a note pad and a pen may be helpful.  Draw your initial list with nodes and pointers between them.  Then follow your code by hand and update the pointers in your drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this step `duplicate.next=new Node(a);` you every time overwrite previous value of `duplicate.next`. You should change reference on `duplicate` on every step when you create next node.

you can use recursion to create copy of the next node and create new node after that:

```
    public Node copy() {
        Node initial= this;
        Node copyNext = this.getNext() == NIL? NIL : this.getNext().copy();
        Node duplicate = new Node(initial.getItem());
        duplicate.next = copyNext;
        return duplicate;
    }
```

and without recursion:

```
    public Node copy() {

        Node currentNode= this;
        Node firstDuplicate = new Node(currentNode.getItem()); //save reference for first node to return
        Node currentDuplicate=firstDuplicate;

        while(Node.NIL!=currentNode.getNext()){
            Node nextNode = currentNode.getNext();
            Node nextCopy = new Node(nextNode.getItem()); //create copy of next
            currentDuplicate.next = nextCopy; //assign this copy as next for current duplicated node
            currentDuplicate = nextCopy; //change reference for current duplicated node to copy 
            currentNode = nextNode; 
        }

        return firstDuplicate;
    }
```

If I understand you right, you need to  create reverted list. In this case you don't need to create new copy of initial list.

```
    public Node reverse() {
        Node head = NIL; //initial we have a empty list

        Node current = this; //set cursor to current node

        while (current != NIL) {
            Node copy = new Node(current.getItem()); //create a copy of current node
            copy.next = head; //set head node as next for copy 
            head = copy; //now move head to copy 
            current = current.next; // move cursor for next position
        }

        return head;
    }
```

to create reverse list with recursion, you just need additional method to keep a reference on previous created copy:

```
    public Node reverse() {
        if (this == NIL) {
            return NIL;
        }

        return reverse(new Node(this.getItem(), NIL), this.getNext());
    }

    private Node reverse(Node head, Node tail) {
        Node copy = new Node(tail.getItem()); 
        copy.next = head;
        if (tail.getNext() == NIL) {
            return copy;
        }
        return reverse(copy, tail.next);
    }
```

Comment: l thought about recursion .  l can't use recursion . l simplify the problem . this is not a function initially; l want to put that in a reverse function . so if l have this in my function reverse l can't call it recursively .

Comment: @MohamedMoka updated my answer with no-recursive approach

Comment: l asked this question because lm trying to do a reverse function and keep the initial list . but  when l run it, my reverse list is the only list . that why l wanted to duplicate a list and use this list  and reverse it . so l added you bit in my function but it still not working . l show you my entire function with your bit :

Comment: @MohamedMoka is it what you are trying to do?

Comment: you right , the only prblem is  I wanted to do it recursively

Comment: my function reverse was working recursivly . but with mine l couldnt keep the original list . thats why l asked how to copy a new list  to use the copy and keep the original after reversing

Comment: @MohamedMoka added recursive variant

Comment: so we cant do it with only  one method recursive ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135219/discussion-between-vlad-bochenin-and-mohamed-moka).

Answer (score 0):

```
public Node reverse(){

    Node p= this;
    Node firstDuplicate = new Node(p.getItem()); //save reference for first node to return
    Node currentDuplicate=firstDuplicate;

    while(Node.NIL!=p.getNext()){
        Node nextNode = p.getNext();
        Node nextCopy = new Node(nextNode.getItem());
        currentDuplicate.n = nextCopy;
        currentDuplicate = nextCopy;
        p = nextNode;
    }


          /* If the list is empty */
          if(firstDuplicate == NIL)
              return Node.NIL;

          /* If the list has only one node */
          if(firstDuplicate.n == Node.NIL)
              return firstDuplicate;

         // Node reverseRest = new Node(p.getItem(),Node.NIL);
          Node rest = new Node(); 
          rest = firstDuplicate.getNext();

          firstDuplicate.setNext(Node.NIL); 
         // Node reverseRest=new Node(p.getItem(),reverseRest);

         Node reverseRest=new Node();
           reverseRest = rest.reverse();

          /* Join the two lists */
          rest.setNext(firstDuplicate); 
          //p=this;
        //  p=p.nthNext(0);
          return reverseRest;
      }
```

Comment: @VladBochenin there is my entire issue above